# semantic web rule use "all"

Tags: jena, semantic-web, jena-rules

Assume that I have the following statements:

```
A p B, A p C, B p C  ( p is a symmetric property, i.e.  B p A, C p A and C p B)
A v 2, B v 1, C v 1,
```

I want to use a rule to do something like:

```
?a p all(?b)
if ?b v 1
than ?a q 'Yes'
```

that means that you can infer (A q 'Yes'), but B can't since B p A and A v 2(although B p C and C v 1).

```
[rule: (?a eg:p ?b), (?b eg:v 1) -> (?a eg:q 'Yes')]
```

I've used the above rule in Jena, but I got A,B,C eg:q 'Yes', which is wrong.
    Any help will be greatly appreciated.

### Update (originally posted as an answer)

the meaning of (?a p all(?b)) is that I like to get a set which all ?mem in this set fulfill the (?a p ?mem). And all member must fulfill (?mem v 1) to infer (?a q 'Yes').

For example,

A p B and A p C,so I get a set which contains (B, C).since B and C v 1,so A q 'Yes.

B p A and B p C,so I get a set(A, C),but A v 2,so can't infer that B q 'Yes'.

**Problem Solved**

Thanks to Joshua Taylor.

Firstly, these two rules can't use at the same time.The rule2 should be used after rule1.

And, the rule2 should be [rule2: (?s ?p ?o) noValue(?s, connectedToNonOne) -> (?s q 'Yes')].

Comment: It's not clear what your rule is supposed to mean.  What is `?a p all(?b)` supposed to mean?  The `if ?b v 1 then ?a q 'Yes'` is understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but I got A,B,C eg:q 'Yes', which is wrong.*

The rule you have actually written in Jena says

For any two individuals X and Y, **if** (X p Y) and (Y v 1) **then** (X q 'Yes').

From the rule you've written, this is correct, by:

(A p C), (C v 1) → (A q 'Yes')
        (B p C), (C v 1) → (B q 'Yes')
        (C p B), (B v 1) → (C q 'Yes')

What you're actually trying to say is:

For any individual X, **if** for every individual Y, (X p Y) *implies* (Y v 1), **then** (X q 'Yes').

In first order logic, your original rule could be written as:

∀ x,y ([p(x,y) ∧ v(y,1)] → q(x,'yes')

What you're actually trying to capture would be:

∀x[(∀y[p(x,y) → v(y,1)]) → q(x,'yes')]

That's harder to capture in Jena rules, because to check whether (∀y[p(x,y) → v(y,1)]) holds or not, all Jena can do is check whether there are *currently* any counterexamples.  If one were added later, you might have incorrect inferences.

Using the builtins available in the rule reasoner, you could do something with [**noValue**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins) and [**notEqual**](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#RULEbuiltins) along the lines of:

```sh
#-- If an individual is disqualified by being
#-- connected to a something that is connected
#-- to something that is not equal to 1, then 
#-- add a connectedToNonOne triple.
[rule1: 
  (?x p ?y), (?y v ?z), notEqual(?z,1)
  ->
  (?x connectedToNonOne true)]

#-- Mark everything that is *not* disqualified
#-- with `q 'Yes'`.
[rule2:
  noValue(?x, connectedToNonOne)
  ->
  (?x q 'Yes')
```

Comment: Yes, I understand the meaning of your rules.The rule1 works perfectly,but the rule2 doesn't work.It returns an (anonymous node, q, 'Yes')statement.

Comment: Thank you so much.Problem solved.Firstly, these two rules can't use at the same time.The rule2 should be used after rule1. And, the rule2 should be [rule2: (?s ?p ?o) noValue(?s, connectedToNonOne) -> (?s q 'Yes')].